# Appending array of map from model in firestore document in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add to an array of maps in Firestore and getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue'
```

This is my Model Class:

```
struct StringModel: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable, Hashable {   
    var id = UUID()
    var cross: Int
    var mains: Int
    var name: String
    var date: Date
}
struct UserDataModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID public var id: String?
    var uid: String
    var strings: [StringModel]?
}
```

Am using the following function to update the value in firestore, however, it doesnt seem to work and throws the error:

```
@Published var newString = StringModel(cross: 50, date: Timestamp(), mains: 50, name: "")

func addString() {
    db.document(uidStr).updateData(["strings" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([newString])]) { err in
        if let err = err{
            print("\(err)")
        }
    }
}
```

Firestore Datatbase

[image]

Any ideas how I can go about this? Thanks!

Comment: did you try to print the actual error? `print("Failed due to: \(error)")`

Comment: Yes I did. Same error. Additionally I have no problem reading data from Firestore its just updating array data.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: We don't know what this `FieldValue.arrayUnion([newString])])` is... [newString]? can  you update your question explaining what that is?

Comment: Your code isn't matching up with the structure in your question.  The data in `strings` is being written but there's an `id` field which is not shown in the structure and the UserDataModel doesn't appear to have a `yob` field. We still don't know what  this `FieldValue.arrayUnion([newString])]` is so the question is very confusing. Can you clarify what's being asked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't append a Swift object to a Firestore array. You must convert the Swift object into a `[String: Any]` object. You can add a computed property to the model that outputs this for you.

```
struct StringModel: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var cross: Int
    var mains: Int
    var name: String
    var date: Date
    
    var firestoreData: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "id": id,
            "cross": cross,
            "mains": mains,
            "name": name,
            "date": date
        ]
    }
}

func addString() {
    db.document(uidStr).updateData(["strings" : FieldValue.arrayUnion([newString.firestoreData])]) { err in
        if let err = err{
            print("\(err)")
        }
    }
}
```